# How to get an Apple Script to click only within a specific display/monitor?

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript

I am trying to program an Apple Script to perform a series of clicks on an application on my second monitor, yet I can only get the clicks to work on my primary monitor. Can someone walk me through how to achieve this behavior?

Comment: UI scripting is almost never needed when working with Applescript. Specify the Application you're working with and what you want to do and we might be able to help you.

Comment: @gurkensaas sure. All in Logic Pro X on the window in my *third display*, I need a script to:
 
1. Click the "gear icon" in the bottom left of the browser. 
2. Select "enable patch merging".
3. Disable-click "sends"
4. Disable-click "Audio Effects"

Comment: I am 99% sure that Logic Pro X doesn't have a scripting dictionary but I think you should add that to your question to clarify your goals. The more information, the better.

Comment: @gurkensaas Absolutely, again though I am really just asking how to get an Apple Script to click on a second display—regardless of the information or application it is clicking on as I may use this for other things in the future. Is it really that complicated?

Comment: Generally speaking in terms of basic _vanilla_ **AppleScript** the `click` _command_ is a part of **System Events**, "**click** v : cause the target process to behave as if the UI element were clicked" and can either `click` a specific **UI element** or "[**at** list of number] : when sent to a "process" object, the { x, y } location at which to click, in global coordinates". As an example the **display** on my left is _secondary_ and on my right is _primary_. Cont'd...

Comment: On the _secondary_ I have a single window opened in **Preview** and from my _primary_ in **Script Editor** I run `tell application "System Events" to click (first UI element of window 1 of application process "Preview" whose description is "close button")` and it closes the _window_ without taking focus away from the _primary_. If I were to programmatically ascertain the `{position, size}` of that **UI element**, I could also use, e.g, `tell application "System Events" to click at {-1737, 79}` to close the _window_. These of course are just _examples_ and there are some caveats too.

Answer (score 2):

In reference to your comment...

> All in Logic Pro X on the window in my third display, I need a script to: 1. Click the "gear icon" in the bottom left of the browser. 2. Select "enable patch merging". 3. Disable-click "sends" 4. Disable-click "Audio Effects"

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** using **Logic Pro 10.6.3** under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

Also note that the *example* **AppleScript** *code* assumes that the **Merge following when loading Patch:** is not showing and **Sends** and **Audio Effects** are **enabled**.

There is also only one **Logic Pro** *window* opened.

In the first *block* of *example* **AppleScript** *code* I experienced a ~5 second delay between the first two `perform action "AXPress" of ¬` *events* and have included a second *block* of *example* **AppleScript** *code* that works around this known ~5 second delay issue, that occurs in some situations, in case you experience it too.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Logic Pro X"
        perform action "AXPress" of ¬
            pop up button 1 of ¬
            group 1 of group 2 of window 1
        perform action "AXPress" of ¬
            menu item "Enable Patch Merging" of ¬
            menu 1 of pop up button 1 of ¬
            group 1 of group 2 of window 1
        perform action "AXPress" of ¬
            checkbox "Sends" of ¬
            group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of window 1
        perform action "AXPress" of ¬
            checkbox "Audio Effects" of ¬
            group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

If you experience the ~5 second delay, try the following...

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
ignoring application responses
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        perform action "AXPress" of ¬
            pop up button 1 of group 1 of group 2 of ¬
            window 1 of application process "Logic Pro X"
end ignoring

delay 0.1
do shell script "killall 'System Events'"
delay 0.2

tell application "System Events"
    run
    delay 0.2
    tell application process "Logic Pro X"
        perform action "AXPress" of ¬
            menu item "Enable Patch Merging" of ¬
            menu 1 of pop up button 1 of ¬
            group 1 of group 2 of window 1
        perform action "AXPress" of ¬
            checkbox "Sends" of ¬
            group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of window 1
        perform action "AXPress" of ¬
            checkbox "Audio Effects" of ¬
            group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

**Notes:**

While the *example* **AppleScript** *code* shown herein worked for me under the conditions specified, nonetheless, it may require adjusting depending upon your conditions, the version of **macOS** and may need some *error handling* added and or the use of the `delay` *command* between some events.

This is a bare minimum *example* and additional coding to check the state of the various **UI elements** should be added to allow for the wanted results to occur without issue. For example, checking whether **Sends** and **Audio Effects** are **enabled** before performing an *action*, etc.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* uses **UI Scripting** and can be *kludgy* and prone to error for a number of different reasons.

---

### Updated Example with Error Handling

Here is an *example*, based on the second *block* of *code* from above, that is coded with additional *error handling* in that it checks to see the **Library** is showing and if not shows it before proceeding, as well as other included *error handling*. The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is also tokenized so setting the *value* of the *properties* in the first group allows for use of languages other than **US English** by adjusting their *value* as appropriate, allowing the remaing *code* to work base on the *value* of those *properties*.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
--  # User adjustable properties, the names 
--  # as they appear on the UI elements.

property |Enable Patch Merging| : "Enable Patch Merging"
property |Sends| : "Sends"
property |Audio Effects| : "Audio Effects"
property menuName : "View"
property menuCommand : "Show Library"
property windowName : "Untitled - Tracks"


--  ##############################################
--  # Do not modify code below unless necessary. #
--  ##############################################

property |Logic Pro| : name of application id "com.apple.logic10"
property |System Events| : name of application id "com.apple.systemevents"
property appName : missing value
property restoreFrontmost : false

tell application id "com.apple.systemevents"
    set appName to name of first process whose frontmost is true and background only is false
    tell application process |Logic Pro|
        if not (exists pop up button 1 of group 1 of group 2 of window windowName) then
            set restoreFrontmost to true
            perform action "AXRaise" of window windowName
            set frontmost to true
            perform action "AXPress" of menu bar item menuName of menu bar 1
            delay 0.2
            perform action "AXPress" of menu item menuCommand of menu menuName of menu bar item menuName of menu bar 1
        end if
        repeat until exists pop up button 1 of group 1 of group 2 of window windowName
            delay 0.01
        end repeat
        if not (exists checkbox |Sends| of group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of window windowName) then
            ignoring application responses
                perform action "AXPress" of pop up button 1 of group 1 of group 2 of window windowName
            end ignoring
        end if
    end tell
end tell

delay 0.1
do shell script "killall " & quoted form of |System Events|
delay 0.2

tell application id "com.apple.systemevents"
    run
    delay 0.2
    tell application process |Logic Pro|
        if not (exists checkbox |Sends| of group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of window windowName) then
            perform action "AXPress" of menu item "Enable Patch Merging" of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of group 1 of group 2 of window windowName
            delay 0.2
        end if
        if the value of checkbox |Sends| of group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of window windowName as boolean is true then
            perform action "AXPress" of checkbox |Sends| of group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of window windowName
        end if
        if the value of checkbox |Audio Effects| of group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of window windowName as boolean is true then
            perform action "AXPress" of checkbox |Audio Effects| of group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of window windowName
        end if
    end tell
end tell

if restoreFrontmost is true then tell application appName to activate
```

**Notes:**

Testing was done with  **Logic Pro X** on a *secondary* **Display** while the *script* was executed from the *primary* **Display**.

If the **Library** in **Logic Pro X** is not showing, focus must be shifted to **Logic Pro X**, however it's restored to whatever was the frontmost *application* before focus was shifted. The shift is very brief and in my testing did not cause any issues. If the **Library** is already showing the focus stays where it's at the time the *script* is executed.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: My god, can I pay you??? This is EXACTLY what I've been looking for and it works PERFECTLY! You are so helpful for typing this all out and demonstrating how it works. Seriously, you are a wealth of knowledge.

I'm wondering, if you have an extra moment -- is there a way in a SEPERATE script to be able to select/enable the "search" bar in the library? I'd try to figure it out myself but I'm still getting a grasp on how to navigate the beautiful script you wrote (i.e, what the "groups" all mean, etc.)